# eclipse text editor fixed line length

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, rcp

I am making an Eclipse plugin and it includes a built-in textEditor implementation, which shall be displaying an SQL query from the database. 
However, I want it to only be allowing to create a 72-character-long lines. Therefore, if i write and endless line, I want it to jump into a new line automatically once the line is 72 characters long.

I am now able to load the statement and display it there, cutting the line at 72 characters, but if i edit the query in the editor, it lets me to create a line at any length. 
I tried to look for a parameter or a method that would set it, but I failed. 
Does anybody have any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What about going for the usual line-wrapping feature? I.e. let the user write lines as long as he want, but provide an option to split these lines *at display* when they reach a certain size. If you really want to add arbitrary linefeeds in the code you're going to run into problems where these linefeeds aren't ignored (e.g. inside quotes)

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yeah, this is how it is done today - when you open a query in an editor, it displays the sql statement in those 72-character-long lines while it is saved as a long String in the database, but I hoped it is possible to make it like this. Tried to look for an attribute, but found none.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try using regular expression .Refer the below link for an example.
http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet196.java